# error if more than 2 inputs

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
if not exist "c:\user_records" md c:\user_records
if [%1]==[] goto ask
set name=%~1
set username=%~2
if name==[] if username==[] (
@echo Error. I don't understand the perameters. Now switching to 
@echo Interactive mode
goto int
)
goto save
:ask
@echo This program allows the user to create a username for them to use.
@echo When asked, please enter your name and chosen username. The
@echo program will create a .txt file with the chosen username as the title.
:int
set /p name="What is your name?"
set /p username="What is your username?"
:save
if exist c:\user_records\%username%.txt (
@echo This username already exists!
set /p username="Please enter another username:"
)
@echo %username%.txt was created
@echo %name% >>c:\user_records\%username%.txt
@echo %username% >>c:\user_records\%username%.txt
@echo %date% %time% >>c:\user_records\%username%.txt
```

if the user gives 1 out of the 2 parameters, or more than 2 then it should display an error message that the parameters are missing and goto int. but instead it takes the first two or just the one. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic solution

```
....
if not "%~2"=="" if "%~3"=="" goto :doSomething
echo Error - Bad arguments
goto :eof
:doSomething
....
```

If you have at least two arguments but not three then start working, else show error and end.

Also note that in your code, the line

```
if name==[] if username==[]
```

is wrong. `name` is just a string and the name of a variable. You need the value associated to the environment variable, that is, you should use `%name%`, the batch way of calling a set variable. When the batch parser reaches the line, it will see the `%name%` reference and will expand it to the value associated to the `name` variable. (This change should also be done in the case of the `username`)

Comment: May I suggest you to not use "read operation" phrase, but "variable expansion" instead? IMHO a _read operation_ is what `set /P` command does...

Comment: @Aacini, I see your point, maybe `retrieve` is a less ambiguous term that `read`, but for me `variable expansion` is the way the parser handles the coded request for value retrieval. I've opted to change it into *`calling`* as it is the term used in Microsoft documentation.

Comment: @Aacini, and refering to the question itself, yes, please, suggest everything you think could help. I have only one head and usually it is not enough.